# How to make a onclick iframe make a button visible?

Tags: javascript

I cant figure out how todo this if i can get any help it would mean alot ove been stumped for the last hour looking everywhere for an awnser maybe im searching the wrong this i dont know. please help thanks!

Comment: Could you explain the problem a bit clearer and describe exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: i wanna make when you click inside iframe it will show a button.

Comment: alot i dont even remeber alot like onclick click events like everything i dont know what im doing wrong

Comment: Display what you have tried and it will give people something to work with an i'm sure someone can then explain why your attempt didn't work.

Comment: Read how to ask with a  [mcve] before asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code to your page inside your iframe. The button will be hidden (see inline style css), when you click within the iframe the click event fires on the body element and displays the button. Uses jquery.

```
<body id="body">
<input id="Btn1" type="button" value="clickMe" style="display:none;">
</body>


$("#body").click(function(){
  $("#Btn1").show();
});
```

Comment: This code is not complete you would need html page with full markup, include jquery, and add script tags to my code. I'm not a free code writing service.

Comment: nope didnt work i have all scripy jquery etc. any not working...

Comment: @tonywicklace that's the code we expect you to post on your question...so please do so.....or it was.,,,,

Comment: You need to post your code. It sounds like you are a newbie. Their are a lot of things you may have done wrong. If you can post the html and the js code we can fix-it. The code i have given you is the chosen way of doing it but my code is not complete. It demonstrates the solution. Applying a click handler to the body, revealing the button.

Comment: I have updated my code their was a $ missing $("Btn1").show();

Comment: thanks i didnt understand the awnser but now i do and it worked thanks!